# Comparing textures in OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: compare, opengl-es-2.0, textures, alpha

I am working on a painting app using the LibGDX framework, though this should be primarily OpenGL related.

Basically, I am looking for a way to prevent the sprites I use to draw from overlapping each other when they aren't fully opaque, as this creates a lot of unpleasant effects.  Drawing the sprites at 1.0 alpha onto a texture and then drawing that texture back at the desired alpha gives the effect I want, but that method would involve constantly recreating the texture as the user is drawing, which is far too intensive to be viable.

From what I can see, the best option for me, in basic terms, is to sort of subtract one of these sprites from the other in the fragment shader.  I am quite certain this route would work, but I cannot figure out how to get to the point where I can actually compare them in the fragment shader.  Both will always use the same single texture, but they will be positioned in different spots.  Is it at all possible to actually compare them like that, or is there a suitable alternative?

Answer (score 1):

It's not actually possible to compare 2 textures that are applied to different geometry (sprites) in the fragment or vertex shader that way, because they will be rendered on different iterations of the shaders, at different points in time.

You could have two or more texture units to sample and subtract multiple textures, but they would have to be applied to the same vertices (sprites), which I think is not what you want.

A better approach would be to compute the proximity of the sprites before they are rendered.  You could then either change their positions, or pass the proxmity as a uniform value into the shaders, which could then be used to change the alpha of the fragment pixels for the sprites.

Comment: As @claymontgomery stated, it is not possible. However, there are some proprietary GL extensions to read color of fragment. This can be sued for custom blending. For example, nVidia's Tegra GPU has `GL_NV_shader_framebuffer_fetch` extension allowing you to read fragment color in GLSL. More info here: https://developer.nvidia.com/sites/default/files/akamai/mobile/files/tegra_gles2_development.pdf
Also, in iOS 6 PowerVR GPU allows to read last fragment data in shaders too (google for `GL_APPLE_shader_framebuffer_fetch`), so in theory this might work in Android too with appropriate drivers.

Comment: Thanks Clay, I sort of figured it was impossible to go the route I was attempting, just wanted to verify.  I'm also not quite sure what you mean by "proximity".  Are you just referring to the position coordinates or something along those lines?  I was trying to figure out something similar to that as well, but I was a bit lost as to how to actually create something useful to my purpose with them. @Keaukraine I will definitely take a look into that.  It seems like a difficult route to go because of the giant array of different devices I would like to support, but I'll see how it goes!

Comment: By proximity, I mean the apparent distance between neighboring sprites.  This is simple to compute from your sprite positions (distance formula) if your camera has a fixed position and you use an orthographic projection, instead of a perspective projection.

Comment: Ah, I do use orthographic projection, though my camera is movable.  What exactly should I look into to see if this route is viable for me?  If I know the general direction to go I should be able to work it out, but I can't quite figure how I'd be able to make this work just by having the distance between the two sprites.

Comment: If the camera moves, then computing the apparent distance between sprites will be more complicated as it depends on the camera position unless maybe the movement is small enough to ignore.

Comment: My camera can move and zoom around pretty drastically, but I will look into how bad it really is in my case.  This does seem like a pretty complicated process for what I assumed would be relatively easy though.  Am I simply going about this whole thing the wrong way?  I've seen it done properly many times in other apps, so maybe there is just an easier route to go than working with each individual sprite like I've been trying.